# How to draw a cylindrical graph in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: graphics3d

I'm trying to plot a graph [ r=3, z=2theta]
Thus, I tried with the function contourplot3D like: contourplot3D [ r=3, z=2theta].
However, it doesn't work. I tried " contourplot3D [ theta=pi/6, z=3]" which is quite similar with the above and it's working well.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Questions about Wolfram|Alpha that are unrelated to Mathematica are off topic on this site, see https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/265/12

Comment: Opps sorry my bad. I didn't know WA was off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
parametric plot3d 3*cos(theta), 3*sin(theta), 2*theta
```

or

```
parametric plot3d 3*cos (theta), 3*sin(theta), 2*theta for 0<theta<4 pi
```

works